# Spark - 'LDAModel' object has no attribute 'describeTopics'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am currently using CDH Spark 1.5.0, Python 2.6.6 Hadoop 2.6

I am trying to build an LDA model by referring to this link [Saprk1.5.0-Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda)

Quoting from what is written in the documentation:

> All of MLlib’s LDA models support:
>
> - describeTopics: Returns topics as arrays of most important terms and term weights
> - topicsMatrix: Returns a vocabSize by k matrix where each column is a topic

I want to implement LDA in describeTopics mode

Code (Reproducible):

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA, LDAModel
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").set("spark.executor.memory", "512m")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sc.setLogLevel('ERROR')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


# Load and parse the data
data = sc.parallelize([[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]])
#data = sc.textFile("file://data.txt")

parsedData = data.map(lambda line: Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in line.strip().split(' ')]))
# Index documents with unique IDs
corpus = parsedData.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]]).cache()

# Cluster the documents into three topics using LDA
ldaModel = LDA.train(corpus, k=3)

# Output topics. Each is a distribution over words (matching word count vectors)
print("Learned topics (as distributions over vocab of " + str(ldaModel.vocabSize()) + " words):")
#topics = ldaModel.topicsMatrix()
topics = ldaModel.describeTopics(maxTermsPerTopic = 10)

for topic in range(3):
    print("Topic " + str(topic) + ":")
    for word in range(0, ldaModel.vocabSize()):
    print(" " + str(topics[word][topic]))
```

However I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'LDAModel' object has no attribute 'describeTopics'
```

describeTopics is not supported by Spark? Is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior. `describeTopics` in PySpark MLLib has been introduced in Spark 1.6:

- [SPARK-8467](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8467) *Add LDAModel.describeTopics() in Python*.
- [`describeTopics` documentatation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=describetopics#pyspark.mllib.clustering.LDAModel.describeTopics).
- [`describeTopics` source.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/933a6548d423cf17448207a99299cf36fc1a95f6/python/pyspark/mllib/clustering.py#L955-L957)

Comment: Please read the document correctly. It is introduced in version 1.5.0 `
`New in version 1.5.0.
describeTopics(maxTermsPerTopic=None)`